# Sum of quadratic residues.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be an odd prime.
Show that $$\sum_{j=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{j}{p}\right) = 0 $$
The case when $$p\equiv 1\pmod4 $$ is easy. What if $$p\equiv 3\pmod4$$

Comment: I reckon it adds up to the number of quadratic residues minus the number of quadratic non-residues.

Comment: @Lord Stark: Yes, obviously. But how to conclude that number residues = number of non residues?

Comment: Doesn't every text on number theory explain that? But anyway, surely the easy case is $p\equiv3\pmod4$ not $p\equiv1\pmod4$?

Comment: @ Lord Stark: can you light the hint for the case $$p\equiv 3(mod4)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

This is equivalent to saying there are as many quadratic residues as non-quadratic residues between $1$ and $p-1$.

By *lil' Fermat* each of these numbers satisfies the equation mod. $p\mkern1.5mu$:
$$x^{p-1}-1=0 \equiv \Bigl(x^{\tfrac{p-1}2}-1\Bigr)\Bigl(x^{\tfrac{p-1}2}+1\Bigr)=0.$$
So each of these $p-1$ numbers is a root of one of these two factors, and $\mathbf Z/p \mathbf Z$ is a field. Can you find out why each factor has as many roots as the other?

Comment: Since $$\mathbb{Z_p}$$ is a field, every polynomial of degree d has atmost d roots.

Comment: Yes, and this particular one has exactly $d$. So it has become a combinatorial question.

Answer (score 0):

It does not really matter if $p\equiv 1$ or $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$. Let $Q$ be the set of quadratic residues in $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$ and $\eta$ be a quadratic non-residue: since the Legendre symbol is multiplicative
$$ \mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^* = Q \cup \eta Q $$
where $Q$ and $\eta Q$ are disjoint. It follows that $|Q|-|\eta Q|$ (which is your sum) equals zero.

Comment: I am stuck with $$ \eta Q $$ what you mean by thi?. Are you taking a cartesian product or what? and how you came to conclude that they have same cardinality?

Comment: @Ravi: $\eta Q$ is the set of non-quadratic residues. $Q$ and $\eta Q$ have the same cardinality since $a\in Q$ implies $\eta a\in\eta Q$.